# Can't establish TLSv1.2 connection from OpenJDK8 to database server

Tags: java, sql-server, ssl, tls1.2

I'm having problems connecting to a database server from my Payara 4.1.2.181 connection pool on OpenJDK 1.8 (installed via homebrew on MacOS).  The error message is at the bottom, but I'll first show my configuration.

```
$ ./bin/java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_372"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_372-bre_2023_04_25_03_16-b00)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.372-b00, mixed mode)
```

```
$ nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 1433 dbserver
Starting Nmap 7.93 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-05-31 22:25 EDT
Nmap scan report for dbserver
Host is up (0.062s latency).

PORT     STATE SERVICE
1433/tcp open  ms-sql-s
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   TLSv1.0: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (secp384r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: server
|     warnings: 
|       64-bit block cipher 3DES vulnerable to SWEET32 attack
|   TLSv1.1: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (secp384r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: server
|     warnings: 
|       64-bit block cipher 3DES vulnerable to SWEET32 attack
|   TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (secp384r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (secp384r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (secp384r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: server
|     warnings: 
|       64-bit block cipher 3DES vulnerable to SWEET32 attack
|_  least strength: C

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 9.63 seconds
```

Inspecting ciphers in the runtime:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.security.*;
import javax.net.ssl.*;

public class AvailableCipherSuites {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // If an argument is present, then remove the
        // jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms restrictions and
        // print all implemented cipher suites. 
        if (args.length != 0) {
            Security.setProperty("jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms", "");
        }

        SSLContext sslc = SSLContext.getDefault();
        SSLSocketFactory sslf = sslc.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket ssls = (SSLSocket) sslf.createSocket();

        ArrayList<String> protocols = new ArrayList(
                Arrays.asList(ssls.getEnabledProtocols()));
        ArrayList<String> enabled = new ArrayList(
                Arrays.asList(ssls.getEnabledCipherSuites()));

        ArrayList<String> supported = new ArrayList(
                Arrays.asList(ssls.getSupportedCipherSuites()));
        supported.removeAll(enabled);
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
        System.out.println("Enabled by Default Cipher Suites");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        protocols.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        enabled.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Not Enabled by Default Cipher Suites");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------");
        supported.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

```
1.8.0_372
Enabled by Default Cipher Suites
--------------------------------
TLSv1.3
TLSv1.2
TLSv1.1
TLSv1
SSLv3
--------------------------------
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV

Not Enabled by Default Cipher Suites
------------------------------------
```

MS JDBC Driver `mssql-jdbc-11.2.0.jre8`:

```
SSLProtocol=TLSv1.2
Encrypt=False
```

Result:

```
SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|SEVERE|81|admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(2)|2023-05-31 22:37:18.751 EDT|TransportContext.java:323|Fatal (HANDSHAKE_FAILURE): Couldn't kickstart handshaking (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No negotiable cipher suite
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloKickstartProducer.produce(ClientHello.java:538)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.kickstart(SSLHandshake.java:510)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.kickstart(ClientHandshakeContext.java:112)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(TransportContext.java:238)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:433)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1795)
)

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|81|admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(2)|2023-05-31 22:37:18.752 EDT|SSLSocketImpl.java:1615|close the underlying socket

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|81|admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(2)|2023-05-31 22:37:18.753 EDT|SSLSocketImpl.java:1634|close the SSL connection (initiative)

WARNING:   RAR8054: Exception while creating an unpooled [test] connection for pool [ MY_DATABASE ], Connection could not be allocated because: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "No negotiable cipher suite". ClientConnectionId:a9f6b85c-072b-4be1-9b43-6038f5937673
SEVERE:   RestResponse.getResponse() gives FAILURE.  endpoint = 'http://localhost:5858/management/domain/resources/ping-connection-pool.json'; attrs = '{id=MY_DATABASE}'
```

When the server first starts, the following can be found in the log, too:

```
SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|99|Thread-17|2023-05-31 22:40:24.742 EDT|SSLCipher.java:487|Transformation RC4 is not available.

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|99|Thread-17|2023-05-31 22:40:24.743 EDT|SSLCipher.java:487|Transformation DES/CBC/NoPadding is not available.

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|99|Thread-17|2023-05-31 22:40:24.743 EDT|SSLCipher.java:487|Transformation RC4 is not available.

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|99|Thread-17|2023-05-31 22:40:24.744 EDT|SSLCipher.java:487|Transformation DES/CBC/NoPadding is not available.

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|99|Thread-17|2023-05-31 22:40:24.750 EDT|SSLCipher.java:487|Transformation DESede/CBC/NoPadding is not available.

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|99|Thread-17|2023-05-31 22:40:24.751 EDT|SSLCipher.java:487|Transformation AES/CBC/NoPadding is not available.

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|99|Thread-17|2023-05-31 22:40:24.751 EDT|SSLCipher.java:487|Transformation AES/CBC/NoPadding is not available.

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|99|Thread-17|2023-05-31 22:40:24.752 EDT|SSLCipher.java:487|Transformation AES/GCM/NoPadding is not available.

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|99|Thread-17|2023-05-31 22:40:24.753 EDT|SSLCipher.java:487|Transformation AES/GCM/NoPadding is not available.

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|99|Thread-17|2023-05-31 22:40:24.755 EDT|SSLCipher.java:487|Transformation AES/GCM/NoPadding is not available.

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|99|Thread-17|2023-05-31 22:40:24.755 EDT|SSLCipher.java:487|Transformation AES/GCM/NoPadding is not available.

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|99|Thread-17|2023-05-31 22:40:24.756 EDT|SSLCipher.java:438|jdk.tls.keyLimits:  entry = AES/GCM/NoPadding KeyUpdate 2^37. AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE = 137438953472
```

UPDATE:

When adding `-Djavax.net.debug=all` to JVm options:

```
SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|ALL|B0|admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(7)|2023-06-01 10:18:06.427 EDT|SSLContextImpl.java:115|trigger seeding of SecureRandom

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|ALL|B0|admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(7)|2023-06-01 10:18:06.427 EDT|SSLContextImpl.java:119|done seeding of SecureRandom

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|SEVERE|B0|admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(7)|2023-06-01 10:18:06.435 EDT|TransportContext.java:323|Fatal (HANDSHAKE_FAILURE): Couldn't kickstart handshaking (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No negotiable cipher suite
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloKickstartProducer.produce(ClientHello.java:538)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.kickstart(SSLHandshake.java:510)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.kickstart(ClientHandshakeContext.java:112)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(TransportContext.java:238)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:433)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1795)
)

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|ALL|B0|admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(7)|2023-06-01 10:18:06.435 EDT|SSLSessionImpl.java:823|Invalidated session:  Session(1685629086431|SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL)

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|B0|admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(7)|2023-06-01 10:18:06.436 EDT|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:71|WRITE: TLS12 alert(handshake_failure), length = 2

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|B0|admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(7)|2023-06-01 10:18:06.437 EDT|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:85|Raw write (
  0000: 15 03 03 00 02 02 28                               ......(
)

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|B0|admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(7)|2023-06-01 10:18:06.437 EDT|SSLSocketImpl.java:1615|close the underlying socket

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|B0|admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(7)|2023-06-01 10:18:06.437 EDT|SSLSocketImpl.java:1634|close the SSL connection (initiative)

WARNING:   RAR8054: Exception while creating an unpooled [test] connection for pool [ MY_DATABASE ], Connection could not be allocated because: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "No negotiable cipher suite". ClientConnectionId:78013a8a-10d1-4c59-9005-ac4e1c34de89
SEVERE:   RestResponse.getResponse() gives FAILURE.  endpoint = 'http://localhost:5858/management/domain/resources/ping-connection-pool.json'; attrs = '{id=MY_DATABASE}'
```

```
SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|98|Thread-17|2023-06-01 21:16:25.854 EDT|SSLContextImpl.java:425|System property jdk.tls.client.cipherSuites is set to 'null'

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|98|Thread-17|2023-06-01 21:16:25.855 EDT|SSLContextImpl.java:425|System property jdk.tls.server.cipherSuites is set to 'null'

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|98|Thread-17|2023-06-01 21:16:25.892 EDT|SSLCipher.java:487|Transformation RC4 is not available.

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|98|Thread-17|2023-06-01 21:16:25.894 EDT|SSLCipher.java:487|Transformation DES/CBC/NoPadding is not available.

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|98|Thread-17|2023-06-01 21:16:25.894 EDT|SSLCipher.java:487|Transformation RC4 is not available.

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|98|Thread-17|2023-06-01 21:16:25.896 EDT|SSLCipher.java:487|Transformation DES/CBC/NoPadding is not available.

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|98|Thread-17|2023-06-01 21:16:25.905 EDT|SSLCipher.java:487|Transformation DESede/CBC/NoPadding is not available.

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|98|Thread-17|2023-06-01 21:16:25.906 EDT|SSLCipher.java:487|Transformation AES/CBC/NoPadding is not available.

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|98|Thread-17|2023-06-01 21:16:25.907 EDT|SSLCipher.java:487|Transformation AES/CBC/NoPadding is not available.

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|98|Thread-17|2023-06-01 21:16:25.908 EDT|SSLCipher.java:487|Transformation AES/GCM/NoPadding is not available.

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|98|Thread-17|2023-06-01 21:16:25.909 EDT|SSLCipher.java:487|Transformation AES/GCM/NoPadding is not available.

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|98|Thread-17|2023-06-01 21:16:25.911 EDT|SSLCipher.java:487|Transformation AES/GCM/NoPadding is not available.

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|98|Thread-17|2023-06-01 21:16:25.912 EDT|SSLCipher.java:487|Transformation AES/GCM/NoPadding is not available.

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|98|Thread-17|2023-06-01 21:16:25.913 EDT|SSLCipher.java:438|jdk.tls.keyLimits:  entry = AES/GCM/NoPadding KeyUpdate 2^37. AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE = 137438953472

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|98|Thread-17|2023-06-01 21:16:25.922 EDT|SSLContextImpl.java:399|Ignore disabled cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|ALL|98|Thread-17|2023-06-01 21:16:25.923 EDT|SSLContextImpl.java:408|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|98|Thread-17|2023-06-01 21:16:25.923 EDT|SSLContextImpl.java:399|Ignore disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|ALL|98|Thread-17|2023-06-01 21:16:25.923 EDT|SSLContextImpl.java:408|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|FINE|98|Thread-17|2023-06-01 21:16:25.924 EDT|SSLContextImpl.java:399|Ignore disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5

SEVERE:   javax.net.ssl|ALL|98|Thread-17|2023-06-01 21:16:25.924 EDT|SSLContextImpl.java:408|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5
```

Comment: does specifying `-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2` affect behaviour?

Comment: Have you tried to include `-Djavax.net.debug=all` to dump the initial TLS packets for additional insight?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you connecting to?  SELECT @@VERSION;  Also, Which OS/version is the SQL Server running on?

Comment: @StrayCatDBA 2019 developer.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov That's what the JDBC driver properties is supposed to do, listed above, configured as part of the connection pool in Payara: `SSLProtocol=TLSv1.2`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning See UPDATE at bottom of question.

Comment: Where's the rest of it? I don't see the `client_hello` packet there.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I added the message from Payara's log (second code block in the update section).   What's in the update is all that's output.

Comment: That's unfortunate. The client_hello packet includes the list of ciphersuites (IDs) that the client is willing to use for the connection. It could be that `sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloKickstartProducer` is sending a different list of ciphersuites than you found are available. I suppose you could try to capture this in Wireshark - it understands the SSL/TLS packets going across the wire until encryption actually kicks in.